# Can I use output of one query as columns in another select clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, listagg

I have one query which gives me column names as output. Eg.

```
select Column_Name from Table1; -- Q1
```

This query gives me `column1, column2` as output.

Now I want to use this output in another query.

```
Select Column1, column2 from Table2; --Q2
```

But in second query I want to get column1 and column 2 from first query dynamically.

I need something like below.

```
Select (Select Column_name from Table 1) from Table2.
```

I want the out put using queries. (I can't use PL/SQL function)

Comment: Are you really not allowed to use any PL/SQL objects, or are you just limited by an application that only understands SQL? And what version of the database are you using? If you are allowed to create PL/SQL functions there are several ways to create PL/SQL objects that *look* like a regular table and can be used in a SQL context.

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes , we are limited by an application that only understands SQL.

Comment: Hi @ManishGoyal, how this application executes the queries? It it some kind of prepared statement that is passed for execution from application? If so you can try to 'simulate' execute immediate /a little expensive one/ - first query database with select 'select ' || listagg(column_name, ',') within group( order by 1) || ' from table 2' from table1. Then result pass as secont request to database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, that's *dynamic SQL* which means that it is PL/SQL which means that you're out of luck.

Comment: with ListAgg function I can get the values as comma separated, but output comes in Parenthesis. Hence it will not understand it as Columns. It's taking it as string.

Comment: As I said: you need dynamic SQL which can be used in PL/SQL procedures. As you can't use PL/SQL, there's nothing much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to hold those columns within another table redundantly. `SYS_REFCURSOR` might be used with a dynamic query within a function as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Tab2_Results RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_tab       VARCHAR2(32) := 'TABLE2';  
BEGIN
     
  v_sql :='SELECT * FROM '||v_tab;
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

Then run the below code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Tab2_Results;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to see the expected result set.

If you need some specific columns, then list their `column_id` values within a Select Statement as in the following code block

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Tab2_Results RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_tab       VARCHAR2(32) := 'TABLE2';  
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG(c.column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.column_name)
    INTO v_cols
    FROM user_tab_cols c
   WHERE c.table_name = v_tab
     AND c.column_id IN (1,4);  
     
  v_sql :='SELECT '||v_cols||' FROM '||v_tab;
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

If you really need to get the concatenated string of columns from another table(`table1`), then use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Tab2_Results RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_tab       VARCHAR2(32) := 'TABLE2';  
BEGIN
  SELECT column_name
    INTO v_cols
    FROM table1;  
     
  v_sql :='SELECT '||v_cols||' FROM '||v_tab;
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

where the query for `table1` returns one row only, as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Issue here is that I can't use PL/SQL block. I can only use normal query. I need to use this query in another application, which doesn't understand pl/sql.

Comment: well, I've added the case, you're welcome @ManishGoyal .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run a query based on the results from another query. Although the below query is a pure SQL statement that returns regular rows and columns that can be understood by any SQL client, you must create custom PL/SQL objects to allow that functionality.

Query:

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        select 'select ' || listagg(column_name, ',') || ' from table2' sql from table1
    ]'
));
```

Results:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2
-------  -------
      1        2
```

Sample Schema:

```
create table table1 as
select 'COLUMN1' column_name from dual union all
select 'COLUMN2' column_name from dual;

create table table2 as select 1 column1, 2 column2, 3 column3 from dual;
```

The above code uses my open source program [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4). While the program uses lots of PL/SQL, the application doesn't know that and will treat your queries like a boring SQL statement.

Other than creating a custom PL/SQL program, the only way to get dynamic SQL in SQL is to use the package `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML` like in [https://stackoverflow.com/q/57174679/409172](this answer). However, that technique only supports a static number of columns, so you would either need to set a maximum number of columns or convert multiple columns into multiple rows.